# Accessing type data wrapped in another type

Tags: f#

I am modelling a protocol in F#.
The protocol states that there is a login command that takes a username and a password as parameters, and there is a logout that takes no parameters.
The commands must be wrapped in some string post- and prefix before the protocol accepts them as a commands.

So far I have got the following model. A `Command` has some data associated with it, and at some point I want to wrap a given command with the post- and prefix.
To do this, I have have a new type called `FormattedCommand` which has a command, and a string representation of the command and the parameters along with the post/prefixes called `SendString`.

When I what to format a command by calling `formatCommand: command:Command -> FormattedCommand` I want to access the command's `CommandString` so I can attach the post/prefixes. How can I achieve this?

```
type CommandData = {
    CommandString : string;
    Parameters : string; }

type Command =
    | Login of CommandData
    | Logout of CommandData

type FormattedCommand = {
        Command : Command;
        SendString : string; }

let formatCommand (command:Command) =
    { Command = command; SendString = ?? }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your requirements correctly, I think that you can make it somewhat simpler.

> The protocol states that there is a login command that takes a username and a password as parameters,
>   and there is a logout that takes no parameters.

I would model that like this:

```
type Command =
   | Login of username:string * password:string
   | Logout
```

> The commands must be wrapped in some string post- and prefix before the protocol accepts them as a commands.

I would model that like this:

```
type FormattedCommand = 
    FormattedCommand of string
```

I don't see why the formatted command needs to know the original command at all. It seems like you're mixing concerns.
If you *do* need to pass them both around, use a tuple or make a simple record type.

> I want to wrap a given command with the post- and prefix.

I would create a function that serializes the command like this:

```
let toFormattedCommand prefix postfix command =
    let commandStr =
        match command with
        | Login (username,password) -> 
            sprintf "%s|Login|%s|%s|%s" prefix username password postfix 
        | Logout ->
            sprintf "%s|Logout|%s" prefix postfix 
    FormattedCommand commandStr
```

I've just used bars to separate the fields. Obviously, the real protocol would be different.

The function above is generic, but you can bake in the default prefix if you like:

```
// bake in the defaults
let toFormattedCommandWithDefaults =
    toFormattedCommand "pre" "post"
```

And then you can create examples like this:

```
let loginStr =
    Login("alice","123") 
    |> toFormattedCommandWithDefaults
// FormattedCommand "pre|Login|alice|123|post"

let logoutStr =
    Logout
    |> toFormattedCommandWithDefaults
// FormattedCommand "pre|Logout|post"
```

Comment: This is good stuff. Compared to the usual OO way, this feels liberating. The need for the formatted command to know about the command is that the protocol eventually hits the ethernet. A response is generated, but it does not contain what it is a response to, so I keep the original command in a closure until the response is received.

Answer (score 3):

you do it like this:

```
let formatCommand (command:Command) =
    let sendString =
        match command with
        | Login data -> 
            // use data.CommandString and data.Parameters to format your result
        | Logout data -> // dito
    { Command = command; SendString = sendString }
```

---

by the way:

- you wrote that your `Logout` should have no parameters, yet you use `CommandData` too
- `Command` and `FormattedCommand` share quite a lot - maybe you should use a ADT here too

Answer (score 2):

```
let formatCommand (command:Command) =
    { Command = command; SendString = match command with
                                      | Login c -> c.CommandString
                                      | Logout c -> c.CommandString }
```